# How can I convert this function into an array function?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

So I have this function here that runs through T2:T:

```
=IF($D$29<$N2,"", AVERAGE(INDIRECT("P"&IF($N2<11, 2,$N2-5)&":P"&$N2+5)))
```

Column P is a list of numbers starting at row 2. Column N is an index(goes up by 1 each row) which starts at row 2 and ends where P ends + 14, and D29 is just a number. In my current situation P ends at row 11 and N ends at row 25. And I'm trying to change it into an array formula so that when I add new rows it updates automatically. So after changing it I got this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($D$29<$N2:N,"", AVERAGE(INDIRECT("P"&IF($N2:N<11, 2,$N2:N-5)&":P"&$N2:N+5))))
```

However, it is not functioning properly. It still occupies the same amount of rows, but each row is the same value. The value of the first row originally. How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that ARRAYFORMULA doesn't work with AVERAGE.
But you could always use javascript.
Open up the script editor and paste in this code.

```
function avg(nums, d) {
  var r = [],
      i, j, start, end, avg, count;
  for(i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if(d <= i) r.push([""]);
    else {
      if(i < 10) start = 0;
      else start = i - 5;
      end = i + 4;
      avg = 0, count = 0;
      for(j = start; j <= end; j++) {
        if(nums[j]) {
          avg += nums[j][0];
          count++;
        }
      }
      r.push([avg / count]);
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Save it, go back to your spreadsheet and put this formula in any cell `=avg(P2:P11, D29)`

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of simply not using an array formula. I even created another script that didn't work.

Comment: I found that your function doesn't work when I expand P, however the following should fix it:
=avg(INDIRECT("P2:P"&(COUNTIF(P2:P, "<>0")+1)), D29)